# Scopus API showing articles from the future

Tags: api, scopus

I'm using Scopus API to extract information about academic papers. However, it's showing something very strange. According to Scopus, many articles are published in the future → see the screenshot. The example shown here was actually published on 5.01.18 [according to Springer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s40008-017-0097-4). Is this an error/bug or have I misunderstood something?

[image: Article from future]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article was brought online on January 5th 2018 as shown in your Springer link.

But it will be officially published in [Journal of Economic Structures 7:1](https://link.springer.com/journal/40008/7/1/page/1), which will be published in December 2018.